# Positive semidefiniteness of symmetric matrix with diagonal = 1 and non-diagonal elements less than 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

Does anyone know any useful results with respect to symmetric matrices with constant diagonals (specifically with respect to whether all eigenvalues are greater than $0$)? I am working on a set of general $n \times n$ matrices with diagonal entries all equal to $1$ and non-diagonal entries between $0$ and $1$  and I am attempting to figure out whether or not this is a subset of positive semidefinite matrices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $3\times3$ matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&-1\\-1&1&-1\\-1&-1&1\end{pmatrix}$ is not p.s.d. but seems to satisfy your conditions.  So the answer to your question has to depend on what particular subsets of matrices you  actually have in mind.

Neither is the matrix  $\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1/2\\1&1&1\\1/2&1&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Most $n\times n$ symmetric matrices are not positive definite (after all, you are asking for all $n$ eigenvalues to be positive).  You should hook your set of matrices to one of the classical sources of psd-ness of symmetric matrices, for instance by exhibiting them as [Gram matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix), or by connecting them via the Fourier Transform and [Bochner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner%27s_theorem) to a positive measure.

Comment: What if I restrict this further to matrices with only positive entries?

Answer (score 1):

In a symmetric matrix with positive entries, if the sum of off-diagonal entries in each row (column) is strictly less than the diagonal entry in this row (column), the matrix is called *diagonally dominant* and is strictly positive. See also *Gershgorin theorem*.

If the matrix is not diagonally dominant,  the eigenvalue with the greatest absolute value (this is spectral radius of the matrix) is strictly positive, and a corresponding eigenvector with strictly positive coordinates can be choosen - see *Perron-Frobenius theorem.*

Comment: Perfect thanks. This gives me good material to work from.

Comment: @user376343 Can you please tell me, does the last paragraph of your answer implies that the matrix will be positive definite. If so, can you please give me any reference where I can find its proof. I am sorry for asking doubt from a question asked 2 years back, but it would be really a great help.

Comment: @Cataclysm  if the off-diagonal entries of your matrices are small enough (in the sence that all $k$-th principal minors of the matrix are positive, the matrix is positively definite. See Sylvester criterion. I think you'l find good theoretical support e.g. in Horn, cited in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_symmetric_matrix) or Meyer: *Matrix Analysis and Applied Linear Algebra*. Also, the wikipedia article I mention here is very useful.